# SonarQube: The web interface cannot be displayed because IE 7 is not supported

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube

I am working with Eclipse and the SonarQube plugin for Eclipse.

If I right-click an issue in the SonarQube Issues window, and click ''Rule description'', it opens the SonarQube Rule Description window. Until recently, I could see an explanation of the rule there. Just now it will show me an error message:

**The web interface cannot be displayed because IE 7 is not supported.

Please switch to a [supported version or another supported browser](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Requirements;jsessionid=B1AFD1848E149CBBC2E6B79B018BE431).**

How can I solve this problem, so that the window shows me the rule description again?

My Eclipse version: Luna M7 Release (4.4.0M7)
SonarQube plugin version: 3.4.0.20140404-0949-RELEASE
My system's default browser: Chrome, Version 35.0.1916.114 m
My Internet Explorer version: 9.0.8112.16421

The error message just doesn't make any sense to me...

Answer (score 4):

I faced same problem on Eclipse Kepler, SonarQube 4.3.1 and IE9. I tried to add -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=9000 at the end of Eclipse.ini but it didn't change anything.

The Internet Explorer compatibility mode was the problem (our SonarQube server is in intranet).

In IE 9:

- ***Tools***, and then select ***Compatibility View Settings***
- Uncheck ***Display intranet sites in compatibility view***
- Restart IE and Eclipse

See Ms Help for more info: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969360/en-gb